# Closed range in Hilbert Space

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

If $H$ is a Hilbert Space. Let $A: H \rightarrow H$ be a one-to-one bounded operator with the additional property that $\beta||u|| \leq ||Au||$.

How would you show that $R(A)$ (the range of A) is closed in $H$?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First suppose we have a convergent sequence $(Au_n)$ in the range of $A$. We'd like to show that the limit of $(Au_n)$ is also in the range.

Note that $(Au_n)$ is Cauchy, and since $\|u_n - u_m\| \leq \|Au_n - Au_m\| /\beta$, we have that $(u_n)$ is Cauchy as well.

By completeness $u_n \rightarrow u$ for some $u \in H$. By continuity $Au_n \rightarrow Au$ so the limit of $(Au_n)$ lies in the range of $A$.