# How to prove an operator is invertible

Tags: operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, inverse, self-adjoint-operators

If A is a bounded, self adjoint operator on a Hilbert space, how can you see that $A^2+I$ is invertible?

Am I not sure how to even start with this, since I don't know anything about the inverse of A... (I thought about showing this by constructing the inverse, but don't see how I could do that here).

Comment: I think you need to consider a geometric series in $A^2$.

Comment: By noting that the [spectrum of $A$ is contained in the real numbers](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/925097/736212), and therefore $A\pm i$, factors of $A^2+I=(A+i)(A-i)$, are invertible.

Comment: Alternatively, spectral mapping theorem and the fact that the square of a real number is nonnegative.

Comment: @RobertIsrael How would you do that? I thought of writing it all out with the ONB, but that's only guaranteed for finite dimensional spaces, no?

Comment: Many functional analysis texts have a version of the spectral mapping theorem suitable for infinite-dimensional Hilbert (or Banach) spaces, see e.g. Rudin, "Functional Analysis", theorem 10.28, or Conway, "A Course in Functional Analysis", VII.4.10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose $(A^2+I)x=0$. Then $\langle x , (A^2+I)x \rangle= \|Ax\|^2+\|x\|^2 = 0$ and so $x=0$. Hence injective.

Now suppose $\langle y , (A^2+I)x \rangle= 0 $ for all $x$, then we see that $(A^2+I)y = 0$ and so $y=0$.

To finish, we need to show the range is closed, we have
$\langle (A^2+I)x , (A^2+I)x \rangle= \langle x , (A^2+I)^2x \rangle \ge \|x\|^2$
and so $\|(A^2+I)x\| \ge \|x\|$ from which it follows that the range is closed and hence
$A^2+I$ is surjective.

Comment: Could you maybe dumb it down a bit? I have issues with understanding of the injectivity/bijectivity. Why is it so that if $<x, Ax> = 0$, then A is injective? And also, where do you get that inequality when you're trying to show the image is closed... and also, why does closure of image mean surjectivity - couldn't it just be a proper closed subset?

Comment: For the first I just used the fact that if $y=0$ then $\langle x , y \rangle = 0$. This them shows that $\|x\| = 0$ and so $x=0$.

Comment: For surjectivity, I showed that the closure of the range (a linear subspace) is the whole space (that is, show $y=0$ above). Then I used a result about closed ranges in Hilbert spaces, see https://math.stackexchange.com/q/594360/27978 for example.

Answer (score 2):

Because $A$ is selfadjoint, we have $\sigma(A)\subset \mathbb R$. Then 
$$
\sigma(A^2)=\{\lambda^2:\ \lambda\in\sigma(A)\}\subset[0,\infty). 
$$
And then
$$
\sigma(A^2+I)=\{\lambda+1:\ \lambda\in\sigma(A^2)\}\subset[1,\infty),
$$
so $A^2+I$ is invertible.